# How can I tell python pandas bar plot to pick color from x label values?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

NOTE: I'm reading two .csv files joining them and grouping them by their fgColor column. (This color has values such as: Green, Blue, Grey, White etc..)

I haven't found a similar example to what I want, so here I am asking a question. This is the line of code I have:

```py
plot_fgColor_Polarity = listing.join(reviews, how='inner').groupby(by='image_dominantfgColor')['Polarity'].mean().sort_values().plot(
    kind='bar', color=['b','orange','brown','r','grey','black','yellow','white','green'])
plot_fgColor_Polarity.set_facecolor('0.90')
```

This is what I get which is expected..

[image]

What I want to achieve is for each bar to automatically (not manually like I did) get its corresponding color based on the value in the data. (that is color names)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I asked too quickly... here is how I'm doing it now:

```py
df = listing.join(reviews, how='inner').groupby(by='image_dominantfgColor')['Polarity'].mean().sort_values()
plot_df = df.plot(kind='bar', color=list(df.index.values))
plot_df.set_facecolor('0.90')
```

This line is what creates the list of colors that I needed.

```py
list(df.index.values)
```